# Rails call controller action on successful object save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, salesforce

I have a user sign up form generated by devise. When the form is submitted and the user object is saved to the database I would like to create and save another object, generated in a separate controller (leads_controller.rb) and pass the user object that was just saved. The sign up form is collecting email, password and password confirmation.

Once the user is saved, I need to pass that user object to the leads_controller to call the new and create actions.

**leads_controller.rb**

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
    include Databasedotcom::Rails::Controller

    def new
      @lead = Lead.new
    end 

    def create
      lead = Lead.new(params[:lead])
      lead.Email = @user.email
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  # User route
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :lenders, skip: :sessions, :controllers => {:registrations => "lenders/registrations"}
  devise_for :businesses, skip: :sessions

  root :to => 'business_account#dashboard', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.class.name == 'Business' }, :as => "business_root"
  root :to => 'lender_account#dashboard', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.class.name == 'Lender' }, :as => "lender_root"

  # Leads route
  resources :leads
```

**registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Lenders::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :update_sanitized_params

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def update
    super
  end

  private

    def update_sanitized_params
       devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :type)}
    end
end
```

Is there an action I can put in my registrations_controller.rb to pass the user object to leads_controller.rb?

Comment: Are you using Lender or User registration controller for sign up

Comment: @ShamsulHaque I am overriding the default users registrations controller with the lenders registrations controller (shown above). I'm doing this so I can somehow call the lead controller and pass the user through to it. I'm just not sure how to do that.

Comment: have you checked that it is coming to lenders registrations controller or not

Comment: @ShamsulHaque yes I've tested the lenders registrations_controller by making it puts to my terminal when creating the object.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the content from

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb
```

and paste into **registrations_controller.rb**

Change **routes.rb**

```
# User route
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
devise_for :businesses, skip: :sessions

root :to => 'business_account#dashboard', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.class.name == 'Business' }, :as => "business_root"
root :to => 'lender_account#dashboard', :constraints => lambda { |request| request.env['warden'].user.class.name == 'Lender' }, :as => "lender_root"

# Leads route
resources :leads
```

In **registration_controller.rb** change the **create action** as

**NOTE**:- see also the change in create action

```
def create
build_resource(sign_up_params)

resource_saved = resource.save
yield resource if block_given?
if resource_saved
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
    expire_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
end
```

In **registration_controller.rb**

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to new_lead_path
  #after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

Devise provide a helper method **current_user** by which you can know **user object** in **leads_controller.rb** and also in **views**

```
class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  include Databasedotcom::Rails::Controller

  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end 

  def create
    lead = Lead.new(params[:lead])
    lead.email = current_user.email
  end
end
```

Comment: Using current_user is a good idea. But I still don't know how to execute leads_controller#new after registrations_controller#create is finished?

Comment: This is great. It is now sending me to leads/new on successful sign up. I'll need to figure out how to redirect that to a different controller in the meantime but I'll mark this answer as correct as soon as I get the current_user info posting to my salesforce database. Thank you!

Comment: I'm running into some issues now that it is all linked together. The user registers, is directed to /leads/new where they are pushed to salesforce as a lead. However, when they are pushed to /leads/new, I am getting "undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass" when I set the email to current_user.email? I'm not sure if a session is occurring to let the email be pulled from the current user?

Comment: I can't access the session data of current_user immediately after they sign up for some reason. If I log in through the login page and navigate to leads/new and submit the form, It has no issue accepting my current_user.email data